# Why do I have many spaces after each data in a cell in my datagridview cell rows data from database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I inserted data into my SQL Server database `Leyte`:

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(con))
{
    myConnection.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select prov_name from tbl_CoopList", con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapt.Fill(dt);

    dgv_CoopList.DataSource = dt;

    myConnection.Close();
}
```

The problem was at runtime, in datagridview, when I double click the cell it has many spaces like:

```
 "Leyte (and a lot of spaces)".
```

I have been trying to solve my problem in how to center my data texts for each cell even though i have this code :

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

I want the result to be the same as what I have inserted in my SQL Server database. How can I possibly erase all the blank spaces so it will be centered automatically.

Comment: are you check why this spaces comes, in db or in logic. without your effort of coding does not give proper answer.  check your double click event and data bind method that the same data you get at run-time or differ.

Comment: @Ajay2707 i edited my question and inserted my code

Comment: @Ajay2707 is it because of datagridview? is it normal?

Comment: no, nothing is manipulated by control. Its logical mistake that you show. Just break point when you get the data from database (above code) and while bind/assign to your gridview. Are you database's table's column is char datatype? if yes, then conver into varchar(100) or whatever you length required.

Comment: What is the data type of your column in the database?

Comment: Take a look at following topics: [char and varchar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) , [nchar and nvarchar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m reasonably certain it’s because you’ve declared your database column type as CHAR (or NCHAR) rather than VARCHAR (or NVARCHAR)

CHAR is a fixed length data type. If you declare a column as being CHAR(10) and then insert the value `foobar` (6 characters) and then query it back, you will get everything between the arrows:

```
>foobar    <
```

This is your six characters of foobar plus 4 spaces to make it up to ten characters for the CHAR(10)

Convert your database columns to VARCHAR (or NVARCHAR)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.DataGridView.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;         
this.DataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders;         
this.DataGridView.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi @Dhruvi, please write your thought too about yours code.